# Determine javascript framework based on importation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am writing a python script that determine the type of javascript framework used in file, I am having issue in detecting when whether the code is node.js file or react.js file. I tried detecting via importation , so far when I have  `import  React from 'react';`  I know directly it is react file , but the problem is when we don't have react importation but the file is part of react project ( for eg file contain reducer, hooks) and I have have othe importation, my idea is to to check whether that importation is react , the problem is even if I check npm registry it don't give me info about whether the package is for node.js apps or for react or other. For example this code ,how can I determine whetehr it is node or react or other ?

```
import { GraphQLScalarType } from 'graphql';

import { Kind } from 'graphql/language';

const LowercaseString = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'LowercaseString',
  description: 'Returns all strings in lower case',
  parseValue(value) {
    return value.toLowerCase();
  },
  serialize(value) {
    return value.toLowerCase();
  },
  parseLiteral(ast) {
    if (ast.kind === Kind.STRING) {
      return ast.value.toLowerCase();
    }
    return null;
  },
});

export default LowercaseString;
```

Comment: If it's just normal JavaScript code that could be implemented in any framework, then you won't be able to determine which framework it was written for.

Comment: yes that's the issue , since the two framwork are based on javascript , the syntax is quite similar, so I don't think it is possible to say the framework type based on code , but I think that may be the importation statement could give extra info

Comment: I have written multiple websites that use the React.js framework **and** simultaneously execute the React code on the Node.js runtime.

Comment: @Quentin can you elaborate more please ?

Comment: Since React.js programs can be run on Node.js, the idea that a module can be written for only one of them nonsensical.

Comment: If I reverse the question , based on which features we can say that this file is node.js file? what do you think